# Mass Assignment Issue Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mass-assignment

I've searched for an answer this this on SO and haven't found it. I'm getting this error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: Brand, Details, Product, Code

I'm uploading csv data from a file into my rails db. Here is the import action from the upload page controller:

```
def import
     Item.import(params[:file])
     redirect_to root_url, notice: "Products imported."
end
```

The attr_accessible line from Item model:

```
attr_accessible :brand, :details, :img, :product, :code
```

I'm using Devise, not sure if that is part of the problem? Do I need to do something in my User model to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Here's the self.import method from Item:

```
  def self.import(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    Item.create! row.to_hash
   end
  end
```

Comment: the `Item#import` method is important here. Can you please post its source?

Comment: BTW: you might want to consider the [strong parameters gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

Comment: Posted the import method, and thanks for the tip about strong parameters. It's working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tip on general debugging — you could also for curiosity's sake take a look at what `params` is at this point or use [pry](http://pryrepl.org/)

```
def import
  raise StandardError, params.inspect
end
```

I also recommend that you use Strong Parameters and I have detailed a clean approach on my blog that you may find useful: [Bootstrapping Strong Parameters in Rails](http://mwdesilva.com/posts/60-bootstrapping-strong-parameters-in-rails-3-2-8).

Comment: Good tip about finding out what's in params. I got the mass assignment issue figured out using strong parameters, but now I'm getting this message upon attempted upload.... 'Required parameter missing: item.' I'm assuming that means that there is some parameter in my table that doesn't match my csv column headers. My suspicion is that my table has timestamps, which aren't referenced in the csv file at all. I can't seem to get a StandardError to show me the params.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, think I got it sorted out.